# AMP pages not getting updated when served from Google's cache

Tags: googlebot, google-cache, amp

I have an amp page at the following UNS and its already cached by Google.
When this paged is served from Google's cache, its showing a **2 day old version** of page.

Original AMP URL
http://www.motachashma.com/amp/articles/ntse-result.php

URL from GOOGLE's Cache
https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.motachashma.com/amp/articles/ntse-result.php

My response header has following for cache control, I was expecting that my page will be updated in cache after few minutes,but its already 2 days.

```
Response header
 Cache-Control:no-store
```

From my server logs I can see Googlebot is coming to this page every few minutes. I even tried the update PING URL from Google but that simply redirected me to my servers AMP URL.

Comment: I think Google considers their cached pages to be an "archive" rather than a "cache".   I think you have to use `noarchive` to stop Google from using that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered that after updating my page was no more AMP compliant and because of that google was serving last valid AMP page it crawled and cached.

Posting it, as it may help others

Answer (score 0):

Give it more time. Sometimes Google takes a bit longer to update its database.

Try using the fetch Google or resubmit the URL to its index.